# How to install rabbitmq management plugin (rabbitmq-plugins)?

Tags: rabbitmq

Brief: Is there a way to install rabbitmq-plugins via a ubuntu package?

Details:

I have rabbitmq running ok in my ubuntu system, and now I'm trying to monitor what's going on via the management plugin. I'm following rabbitmq.com/management.html instructions, but can't execute

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

because my system does not have rabbitmq-plugins installed.

It's Ubuntu 11.10, and came with rabbitmq installed as a package (aptitude install rabbitmq-server librabbitmq-dev). The config and the server are running fine (the installed version is 2.5.0).

Thought that the plugin would get installed by installing "sudo aptitude install rabbitmq-plugins-common", but doing that does not install rabbitmq-plugins.

Is there a package that will install the plugin? I'd like to avoid if possible having to purge the rabbitmq server that is running ok, and then reinstall it via a download + build from source, all just to get the plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update your `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the latest rabbitmq distribution

```
deb http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian/ testing main
```

Comment: GPG error: http://www.rabbitmq.com testing Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F7B8CEA6056E8E56

Answer (score 2):

1st edit your /etc/apt/sources.list as above, 
then add the key to your your trusted key list.
you can find the needed command in following link. 
Link: http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html